# How to input decimal parameter in web3.py?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-deployment, web3.py, python, vyper

I have a contract with this abi

```json
[
  {
    "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
    "type": "constructor",
    "inputs": [
        {"name": "longitude", "type": "fixed168x10"},
        {"name": "latitude", "type": "fixed168x10"}
    ],
    "outputs": [],
    "gas": 105370
  },
  ...
]
```

When I tried to create the transaction to make contract like this

```py
contract = w3.eth.contract(bytecode=bytecode, abi=abi)

latitude = 0.0
longitude = 0.0
constructor = contract.constructor(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude)
```

this error showed up

```py
TypeError: One or more arguments could not be encoded to the necessary ABI type.  Expected types are: fixed168x10, fixed168x10
```

I tried to change the longitude and latitude type to

```py
from decimal import Decimal

latitude = Decimal(0.0)
longitude = Decimal(0.0)
constructor = contract.constructor(latitude=latitude, longitude=longitude)
```

But the error keep showed up. How can I put decimal parameter to contract function?

Edit: I made the contract using vyper and clearly in vyper documentation state there is type decimal [here](https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/types.html#decimals)

Answer (score 1):

Solidity does not have floating points or decimals. Thus, all numbers need to be converted to [fixed point math](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_arithmetic).

[Here the relevant Solidity documentation](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.5/types.html#fixed-point-numbers).

The `168x10` means that that there are 168 bits for the whole part of the number and 10 decimal points for the fractions.

Thus, you need to shift your number 10 decimal left.

`fixed_point = int(value * (10**10))`

Comment: Why is it become integer and not floating point number?

Comment: `Solidity does not have floating points or decimals. ` Please let me know if there is something if you do not understand about this part.

Comment: I'm using `vyper` and there is `decimal` type data in `vyper`. Why should I put integer then?

Comment: I suggest you study the Vyper documentation, as it explains the correct number of decimals: https://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/stable/types.html#decimals